# How to get back to window.opener page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a window A which uses window.open to open Window B. When I click on the home button in window B, I need to close window B and get the focus back to window A. TO accomplish the task, I check if the window A is still open by using $window.opener && !$window.opener.closed.Once its confirmed that window A is still open, I use $window.opener.focus to put the focus back on the window A and I use $window.close to close window B. But there are scenarios which need attention.

I need suggestions for 2 scenarios.

1. After opening window B, if window A is changed to some other page, let's say www.cnn.com, how do I check if my window A still points to my page or at least my domain?
2. My window A and window B are two tabs, if there is some other tabs say window C is opened and the window C tab is placed in between tab A and tab B, with my existing code, when I click on home button, window B is closed and window C is show., instead how to switch back to window A tab?

Please let me know if I am missing some details.

Comment: I would suggest against this due to security issues with leaving original window open to attack https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/

Answer (score 0):

You can use localStorage to store each active url on your domain in an object on page load. Then when you leave the page remove it from the the object and update the storage.

```
var pages;
window.onload = ()=> { 
    pages = localStorage.getItem("pages") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("pages")) : {};
    pages[window.location.href] = true;
}

window.onbeforeunload = ()=> {
    pages[window.location.href] = false;
    localStorage.setItem("pages", JSON.stringify(pages));
}
```

At any time you want to see if the page is still open use

```
if(pages["myurl"]){
    // do something
}
```

Comment: How can I check if that particular Window A page is still open?

Comment: Use the second code block but replace "myurl" with the url of page A.

Comment: Lets consider a scenario: if 3 copies of window A are opened (lets say A.1, A.2, A.3) and if window B is opened from A.1 and if I close or change URL of A.1 window. 

When home button is clicked on Window B, if I try to use the second block of the code, since A.2 and A.3 are still open, the pages"myUrl" will return true., where my Window A.1 is not present, how to handle that?